# Orion Context Broker: reset by peer when calling updateContext

Tags: fiware-orion

Just after the install of the Context Broker I've tried to test it creating a new entity as described in the session Entity Creation of https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide, but I'm getting a "connection reset by peer" error.

The log doesn't seem say anything, even I raised the level of traces with -t 0-255 option.

Aditional info:

```
$ contextBroker --version
0.14.0

$ ps aux | grep context
/usr/bin/contextBroker -port 1026 -logDir /var/log/contextBroker -pidpath /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid -dbhost localhost -db orion -t 0-255
```

Comment: brdev, please edit your question to add three additional pieces of information: 1) the result of `curl localhost:1026/version`, 2) the output of the `md5sum /usr/bin/contextBroker` command, 3) the output of `rpm -aq | grep prelink` command. Thanks!

Comment: fgalan, before your response I've updated the context broker to the new 0.14.1 and it start working magically, so I can't help on finding the issue anymore. But thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed updating the Context Broker to a newer version, in my case to version 0.14.1, which can be found here: http://repositories.testbed.fi-ware.org/repo/rpm/x86_64/.

I can't say exactly what was wrong, since after updating everything was working fine.

Comment: It makes sense: this kind of problem could be related (I tell "could be" and not "is" because we didn't end debugging so I cannot assure ;) with prelink, which (without entering into too much detail) is a background process that can corrupt the contextBroker binary. The 0.14.1 RPM includes an exclusion file to avoid prelink ruinning the contextBroker binary.